# Microsoft Teams messaging extension icons keep disappearing for a custom app

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We have developed messaging extension which we install by using "Upload a custom app" into different teams and channels in MS Teams. Couple a days after installing these messaging extensions, icons of these extensions start disappearing. Attached here is the screenshot -

[image]

We have tried clearing cache, upload the icon in the Azure portal again, and redeploy the bot but nothing has worked so far. Any help as to why this happens and what is the solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to confirm before I take this forward to respective team, Did you try follow guidelines for icons? For more info please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64595782/microsoft-teams-messaging-extension-icons-keep-disappearing-for-a-custom-app)

Comment: Hey Manish yes i did. Everything seems to be working fine when we install it. It all gets messed up after a couple of days.

Comment: @Manish-MSFT is there a team i can get in touch with about this ?

Comment: I have fowarded this to respective team, I am quite sure for it to be bug. I will update you with response from the team.

Comment: this is most likely due to the icon not getting claimed correctly. In that scenario the icon is available for ~24 hours but then is deleted. To investigate this further we will need you to send us a fiddler trace of the upload API call that was used to create the app that later disappeared. You can send this trace to microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com. Please once confirm here after sending so that your request will be taken forward to engineering team.

Comment: Hey @Manish-MSFT we have sent the email with fiddler session.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows the missing icon on the tool bar. How about trying to updating Teams client to the latest version?

I don't have enough reputation to add an comment, sorry for my adding an answer directly.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for replying. But yes its the latest version, just updated 2 days ago.

Comment: At first, I googled your description but didn't get any usful message. Then I tried to use fiddler to catch the icons deserved location but failed.  I also searched the local installation address for the icons but failed too. So I am afraid that Teams bug leads to the phenomenon。

Comment: Thanks for trying.